# How would you set up this integral to where you can perform Simpson's rule?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, simpsons-rule

Not sure how to set up my deltax or even begin with this setting this problem up in general. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: integral]

Comment: For starters, $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$. What are the given $a$, $b$, and $n$?

Comment: @zipirovich a = 0 b = pi/2 and n = 10? The constant out front and theta(0) = 42 degrees is throwing me off

Comment: $a$, $b$, and $n$ -- yes. As for what $\theta$ and $\theta_0$ mean... The problem starts with a reference to a figure that you didn't reproduce. I suspect the figure (and possibly some narrative earlier in the textbook) explain what they are. Without seeing the figure, I can't tell that.